# How to process URL parameters that are not in a variable name

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am working on a spring web applications that are supposed to have URL parameter to be passed into the page.
like

```
xyz.com/listing?type='Hotels'
xyz.com/listing-details?id=53
```

But When I am looking at the approach followed by other websites. It looks to be something like

```
xyz.com/listing/Hotels
xyz.com/listing-details/335
```

How Can I adjust my spring controller to fetch these parameters out of the URL.

Currently my controller method looks like this for xyz.com/listing?type='Hotels'

```
public ModelAndView getContactList(@RequestParam(value = "type", defaultValue =       "Hotels") String type, HttpServletRequest request) {
  Some Code
}
```

Also how can I show a 404 page when the request Parameter is not in the proper format and I don't find any results associated with that.

Comment: `@PathParam` will help you.

Comment: To match only when the user provides a particular GET param, you can do something like this: `@RequestMapping(params = "type=Hotel")`.  I believe it can use regular expressions as well, and accepts a single string param or an array of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@PathVariable` instead of `@RequestParam`

Assume you have Hotels `1`-`500` and you would like to return result if the number is less than `500`. If the Hotel Number exceeds `500` then you want to return `Resource Not Found 404`.

Valid URLs:

```
xyz.com/hotels
xyz.com/hotels/335
```

Invalid URL:

```
xyz.com/hotels/501
```

Define the controller as below:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hotels")
public class HotelController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getHotels(){
        System.out.println("Return List of Hotels");
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("hotel");
        ArrayList<Hotel> hotels = null;
        // Fetch All Hotels
        model.addObject("hotels", hotels);
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{hotelId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getHotels(@PathVariable("hotelId") Integer hotelId){
        if (hotelId > 500){
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException();
        }
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("hotel");
        Hotel hotel = null;
        // get Hotel
        hotel = new Hotel(hotelId, "test Hotel"+hotelId);
        model.addObject("hotel", hotel);

        return model;
    }
   }
```

Note `@RequestMapping` given as `/hotels`, this way the `getHotels()` method would be invoked when the URL is

```
xyz.com/hotels
```

and the request method is `GET`.

If the URL contains id information like `xyz.com/hotels/2` then the `getHotels()` with the `@PathVariable` would be invoked.

Now, if you want to return `404` when the hotel id is greater than `500`, throw a custom `Exception`. Notice `ResponseStatus.NOT_FOUND` is annotated in the custom exception handler method below:

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
class ResourceNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ResourceNotFoundException(){
        super();
    }
}
```

Comment: HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND written in the above method can be imorted as org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND

Answer (score 2):

Check out Spring's @PathVariable. One relevant tutorial is [this](http://www.javabeat.net/pathvariable-template-patterns-spring-mvc/)

From the above tutorial you can see that you can write code like the following (where you can see the flexibility of Spring MVC)

```
@Controller
public class TestController {
     @RequestMapping(value="/user/{userId}/roles/{roleId}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public String getLogin(@PathVariable("userId") String userId,
         @PathVariable("roleId") String roleId){
         System.out.println("User Id : " + userId);
         System.out.println("Role Id : " + roleId);
         return "hello";
     }
     @RequestMapping(value="/product/{productId}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public String getProduct(@PathVariable("productId") String productId){
           System.out.println("Product Id : " + productId);
           return "hello";
     }
     @RequestMapping(value="/javabeat/{regexp1:[a-z-]+}",
           method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public String getRegExp(@PathVariable("regexp1") String regexp1){
           System.out.println("URI Part 1 : " + regexp1);
           return "hello";
     }
}
```

A Controller is not limited to using only @PathVariable. It can use a combination of @PathVariable and @RequestVariable that fits the particular needs.